# Error on getting response from HttpClient using Jetty 9

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, jetty-httpclient

I want to get content from an external server using Jetty and HttpClient class. Now I want to copy the obtained response as `HttpServletResponse` and return to client (Browser). I've tried something but cannot succeed. I think I am not getting through with inner class.

Here is my code:

```
public void getContentsTo(String uri,HttpServletRequest request,final HttpServletResponse response){
        HttpClient httpClient=new HttpClient();
        httpClient.newRequest(uri).send( new org.eclipse.jetty.client.api.Response.CompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Result result) {
                response=(HttpServletResponse)result.getResponse();
            };
        });
```

The error is in assigning `response` as:

> The final local variable response cannot be assigned, since it is
>   defined in an enclosing type

If I dont use `final` for the parameter there is also a error as ,

> Cannot refer to a non-final variable response inside an inner class
>   defined in a different method

What is the cause?

Answer (score 1):

The result.getResponse() response is a org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpResponse which does not have HttpServletResponse anywhere in its lineage.  If I follow what you are trying to do you will need to copy out the information in the Result you getting and put it into your HttpServletResponse object.

Comment: Ok! the error is not on typecasting, I think error is on setting outerclass variable from innerclass.

Comment: sure, but it is final, you can not _replace_ the object like you are showing..for that reason _and_ that they are completely different object types.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `final` (!) variable in the params and you try to change it in the code. That could be the cause of the error.

Why is it `final`? Remove this identifier and try again.

Ok, I would try to do like that.

If you don't use the `response` parameter in the code, as I can see, why don't you declare it inside the inner class as an instance variable?

Comment: final in the code was suggested by my first error. Error is as:"Cannot refer to a non-final variable response inside an inner class defined in a different method"